# JSON notation in angular 6 for Http Post

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular6

I am new to Angular 6 and trying to POST data using Angular 6.

I am using the following format to send data as JSON:

```
var PostData = 
      { 'username': this.user, 
        'password': this.pwd 
      };
```

This is the data being as seen in the console:

```
{username: "admin", password: "admin"}
password: "admin"
username: "admin"
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ ()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

I am getting a credential error.

However when I do an ajax post.
I am getting a pass on the request.

This how the data is going :

```
Object { username: "admin", password: "admin" }
```

My understanding is that I am sending the data in angular as a JSON object.

I am at a stand still and don't understand why the credentials are passing in one and not in another.

This is the code to my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],

})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  user: FormDataEntryValue;
  pwd: FormDataEntryValue;

  _url: string;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this._url = 'http://localhost:7080/login';
   }

  ngOnInit() { }


  formSubmit(event: any) {



    var username:FormDataEntryValue;
    var password:FormDataEntryValue;

    var form: HTMLFormElement = document.querySelector('#loginform');
    const formData: FormData = new FormData(form);
    this.user = formData.get("username");
    this.pwd = formData.get("password");

    var PostData = 
      { 'username': this.user, 
        'password': this.pwd 
      };
    console.log(PostData);

    this._http.post<any>(this._url, PostData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }).subscribe(
      data => console.log('Success!', data),
      error => console.error('Error!', error)
    )



  }


}
```

html button for a form in the component:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type='button' name='submit' (click)="formSubmit(event)">Login</button>
```

Comment: "A pass on the request"? What do you mean? What is the error?

Comment: @ChrisNeve well by pass I mean that the login is successful i.e. the data posted is going in ht right format or so I believe. By not passing I mean that though the post to the end point is successful  , the required result is not obtained ; maybe as the data is not going in the right format. I researched about how to send JSON objects, and am confused if I am sending it wrong:)

Comment: So the POST to the end point is successful, but the required result is not obtained; could it be a problem on your backend?

Comment: @ChrisNeve Nope tried the same with an ajax request in a simple html file and I am getting the required result; this has left me confused!!!